# Is the Chelmsford England / "Hawaii" UFO Lights sighting video faked?

Tags: video, ufo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzSKsma0mFw

Video is being passed around as a UFO or "Mystical Light" sighting over Chelmsford, UK, or in some cases "Hawaii".

Are the lights special effects added in post production or faked in other ways?

Comment: What is the claim here? That this is a true representation of the appearance of the sky?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clear what exactly you are skeptical of, and could be considered an opinion question.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella what is unclear here?  Skeptical of video authenticity.

Answer (score 3):

It's very unconvincing. The [Essex chronicle](http://www.essexchronicle.co.uk/VIDEO-UFO-sighting-Chelmsford-Ingalterra/story-19352334-detail/story.html), commenting on [a better copy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auV7Q73cToI), dated a year later, interviewed [Mark Pickering](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/mark-pickering/58/765/953), certainly a relevant expert, on the subject:

> Like all these videos, it's not shot professionally and when it zooms in the size of the orbs changes perspective. It's all things that are very easy to do on a computer. I have put a UFO on a music video myself and this one is no better than that.
>
> Students in the technology department can do it quite easily and it's definitely inconclusive. That's my verdict.

Comment: Here is one [Youtube video commenter](https://plus.google.com/116017334429135443961/posts/JQzDU6vxRuU) claiming that the pixelation of the objects and background differs. But this claim is not substantiated with numbers or screenshots, and I doubt that you can accurately distinguish pixellation on a video of Youtube quality.

Comment: How can a 'better copy' turn up one year later?

Comment: It can be published by the same, better original source?